# How do you create those Harry potter wand sounds?

Tags: sfx, movies

Here's a few isolated SFX from the HP movie.

I'm wondering how to recreate those SFX. 
Any idea ?

Comment: Hi @Florian.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There's no set way of making these sounds, the first one sounds like lighting/electricity mixed with some sort of computer generated sound from a synth.
Second one is something being pitched down again, maybe a synth.
Third one, sounds like an explosion and again, mixed with a digital sound.

Of course, this is just my opinion and I could be completely wrong, but that's the fun of sound design. You can make anything sound like anything!

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember from the movies, I think the sounds are more composed of electric-arc(ish) type sounds and whatever sound helps to distinguish the wands or wizards from each other; some wands are more shrilling then others, and some sound more windy, etc...